# Choosing q objects from k sets of varying sizes with at most one choice per set

Tags: combinatorics

What is the general formula for selecting $q$ objects from a collections $K$ of different sets $k\in K$ of varying sizes $S(k)$ such that each of the $q$ selected objects are in different sets $k$? (note: the objects $j_k$ in each set $k$ are unique)

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "formula for selecting $q$ objects" you mean the *number of ways* this can be done.

Firstly, we choose $q$ of the sets in $K$. Let's say these sets are $k_{i_1}, \ldots ,k_{i_q}$. There are $\binom{\vert K\vert}{q}$ ways to make this choice.

For this choice of sets, the number of ways to select $q$ objects, one from each set, is $S(k_{i_1})\times \cdots\times S(k_{i_q})$.

Unfortunately, I don't think the total reduces to a simpler formula than this:

$$\sum_{\{k_{i_1}, \ldots ,k_{i_q}\} \subseteq K}{\left(\prod_{r=1}^{q}{S(k_{i_r})}\right)}$$